# Allow hiding Stack Snippets (or code block that long enough) on Android app

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, code-block, stack-snippets

On Stack Overflow, I'm not a regular in [html](/questions/tagged/html), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), or [css](/questions/tagged/css), so I rarely encounter Stack Snippets. But when I browse ["Page not found" is a bit of a mess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284924/page-not-found-is-a-bit-of-a-mess), I didn't expect the snippet to be *that* long, and scrolling all the way on my not-so-small-but-no-so-big-screen Nexus 4 is... not fun.

Perhaps that's one of the reason why Stack Snippets can be hidden on browser. Even if we press "Show code snippet", the code-block will be shown with vertical scroll bar, preventing the need to scroll down all the way. This behavior also applies to general long code-block on browser ([example post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559781/2821954)).

Now, I am *not* suggesting to add scroll bar for code-block in Android app since AFAIK adding `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView` is generally not a good idea. (It might confuse the app whether you want to scroll the post, or the code-block, and personally it annoys me anyway).

The problem is, I'm not sure how we can display these important elements of SO efficiently on native app.

At least, I'd want to request a feature to enable hiding/showing Stack Snippets on Android app. Bonus point if it can also be applied to long code-block (minimum of 30 lines?).

Or else, do you have any other suggestions?